# How to keep a centred div in the boundaries of the browser window (vertically and horizontal)?

Tags: css, ios, html

I'm trying to make it so that both the image and links stay in the browser window all the time. This is the [site](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3980495/5PORE/HTML/index.html). When loading it on an iPad, the centred content is bigger than the window as shown [image: here].

I'd like it to display like [image: this] (obviously without black borders). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The trick to center an element without any additional markup, is to use `translate`:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QE8KV/

---

**P.S.** Don't forget the vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

The proble of Joseph Silber's answer is that if the window is smaller than your content, the content gets cutted.

Then you can use a trick with floating: http://jsfiddle.net/QE8KV/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="center">Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#top {
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    width: 100%;
}
#center{
    background: #2D285E;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #231E5C;
    color:white;

    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I tried playing around with this, I just couldn't get it to do what I want. I want the central image/text to always expand to 80% of the pages width or height (with min and maxs) but so it keeps the width:height ratio, will this achieve that?

Comment: @Supertod No, that won't keep the aspect ratio. But if you want that, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170261/how-to-auto-resize-a-div-with-css-while-keeping-aspect-ratio