# Lay out children with equal space between each other to fill container

Tags: css, layout, html

I have a `div` with a variable width, and I have a variable amount of children inside this div. I want the children to fill up the space inside the `div`. I first tried to change the `div` to `display:table` and the children to `display:table-cell` but I ended up all the children filling up all the space and not obeying their `width` and `max-width` properties. Then I've tried the table approach: I've changed the `div` to a `table` (yes, I know, it's not recommended, that's why I'm probably here asking) and wrapped the children into a `tr` and each in `td`s, but I ended up all the children cells filling up the whole space, but aligned to left (I've set the children `div`s `display:inline-block`):

[image]

If I change the alignment to `center`, I get this:

[image]

They are centered, but I still get spaces on the left and right of the parent (with the yellow background that I've set for distinguishing). What I actually want is this:

[image]

I've achieved this by setting the first `td` to align text to left, the second to center, the third to right. But I may have more of these thumbnails, so I need a general solution.

How can I lay out a variable number of children inside a container to fill the width, with the first element starting at the exact left border of the container (unlike the second image) and the last element ending at the exact right border of the container (like shown in the third image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span id="s1"></span>
    <span id="s2"></span>
    <span id="s3"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    background: #ff6;
    text-align: justify; /* Important */
    font-size: 0; /* Used to remove spaces */
}
div:after{ /* Used to create a new last line */
    content: '.';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

span{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Use your widths, min-widths and max-widths here: */
#s1{
    background: red;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 150px;
}
#s2{
    background: green;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
#s3{
    background: blue;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6Rw/)

You can obtain equally spaced boxes using `text-align: justify` on the wrapper. The problem is that it doesn't work for the last line (which in this case is the first too), so you can either use [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last), or an `:after` pseudo element with `width: 100%` in order to create a new last line.

Comment: that works perfectly, but (in addition), is it possible to make the children shrink (respecting their aspect ratio) if there is not enough space? it is an html for thumbs on a website, and it the size is not enough, i'd like those thumbs to shrink in space (if they come near e.g. 10px between each other) instead of the last one going down to the next line. or if it's not possible without heavy use of js, is it possible to hide the last element if there's no enough space, e.g. only two thumbs will be displayed on a narrow screen, four or five thumbs would be displayed on wide screen etc.?

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Yes, it's possible. Just use `width` percentages and remove the `min-width` properties. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6Rw/1/)

Comment: well, this (the demo) is not exactly what i want. i want the thumbnails to preserve their size unless the margin between them is, say, 10px, and *only* then, they should start getting smaller as i make the viewport smaller, *respecting the aspect ratio*..

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Be aware that mixing percentages and constant values like 10px won't work on old browsers. But if you don't mind, be sure all widths sum up 100%, add borders and use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)  ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6Rw/2/)). Or maybe you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu And if you want to keep aspect ratio, you can use http://stackoverflow.com/a/12180761/1529630. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6Rw/3/)

Comment: the last one is exactly what i need. thank you, i'll be implementing that.

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu The previous fiddle had a bug: in order to remove border separations before the first element and after the last one I used `border-[left/right]-width:0`, but that increased the height of the first and last element. I have fixed it with `border-[left/right]-color:transparent`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kx6Rw/5/)